# Error Inserting data in Database using Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, ticket-system

I'm working in a ticket system for my company using PHP and Prepared Statement.
When you add a ticket, you're supposed to fill these fields:

1. Ticket type
2. Ticket title
3. Ticket description
4. Date requested
5. Hour requested
6. Company
7. Type of visit
8. Priority
9. Status
10. Technician assigned

**This works:**
1. You can select the type of ticket pulled from the database.
2. You can select the company pulled from the database.
3. You can select the type of visit pulled from the database.
4. You can select the technicians pulled from the database.

The issue is that when you press on add ticket, it won't add anything to the database.

Here's my code:

**newticket.php**

```
<?php
   $projects = ProjectData::getAll();
   $priorities = PriorityData::getAll();
   $ticket= TicketData::getAll();
   $statuses = StatusData::getAll();
   $kinds = KindData::getAll();
   $users = UserData::getAll();

   ?>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-header" data-background-color="blue">
            <h4 class="title">Nuevo Ticket</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="card-content table-responsive">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="./?action=addticket">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                     <select name="kind_id" class="form-control" required>
                        <?php foreach($kinds as $p):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $p->id; ?>"><?php echo $p->name; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                     </select>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Titulo</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                     <input type="text" name="title" required class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Titulo">
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Descripcion</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                     <textarea class="form-control" name="description" required placeholder="Descripcion"></textarea>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Fecha de la Visita</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <input name="date_at" id="date_at" class="form-control" type="date">
                  </div>
                  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Hora de la Visita</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <input name="time_at" id="time_at" class="form-control" type="time" />
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Proyecto</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <select name="project_id" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">-- SELECCIONE --</option>
                        <?php foreach($projects as $p):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $p->id; ?>"><?php echo $p->name; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                     </select>
                  </div>
                  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Categoria</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <select name="category_id" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">-- SELECCIONE --</option>
                        <?php foreach(CategoryData::getAll() as $p):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $p->id; ?>"><?php echo $p->name; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                     </select>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Prioridad</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <select name="priority_id" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">-- SELECCIONE --</option>
                        <?php foreach($priorities as $p):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $p->id; ?>"><?php echo $p->name; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                     </select>
                  </div>
                  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Estado</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <select name="status_id" class="form-control" required>
                        <?php foreach($statuses as $p):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $p->id; ?>"><?php echo $p->name; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                     </select>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Asignar a</label>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                     <select name="tecnico_id" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="">-- SELECCIONE --</option>
                        <?php foreach($users as $p):?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $p->id; ?>"><?php echo $p->name." ".$p->lastname; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                     </select>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Agregar Ticket</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**ticketdata.php**

```
<?php
class TicketData {
    public static $tablename = "ticket";


    public function TicketData(){
        $this->name = "";
        $this->lastname = "";
        $this->email = "";
        $this->password = "";
        $this->date_at="";
        $this->time_at="";
        $this->tecnico_id="";
        $this->created_at = "NOW()";
    }
    public function getTicket(){ return TicketData::getById($this->ticket_id); }
    public function getProject(){ return ProjectData::getById($this->project_id); }
    public function getPriority(){ return PriorityData::getById($this->priority_id); }
    public function getStatus(){ return StatusData::getById($this->status_id); }
    public function getKind(){ return KindData::getById($this->kind_id); }
    public function getCategory(){ return CategoryData::getById($this->category_id); }

    public function add(){
        $sql = "insert into ticket (title,description,date_at,time_at,category_id,project_id,priority_id,user_id,status_id,kind_id,created_at,tecnico_id) ";
        $sql .= "value (\"$this->title\",\"$this->description\",\"$this->date_at\",\"$this->time_at\",\"$this->category_id\",\"$this->project_id\",$this->priority_id,$this->user_id,$this->status_id,$this->kind_id,$this->created_at,$this->tecnico_id)";
        return Executor::doit($sql);
    }

    public static function delById($id){
        $sql = "delete from ".self::$tablename." where id=$id";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }
    public function del(){
        $sql = "delete from ".self::$tablename." where id=$this->id";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }

// partiendo de que ya tenemos creado un objecto TicketData previamente utilizamos el contexto
    public function update(){
        $sql = "update ".self::$tablename." set title=\"$this->title\",category_id=\"$this->category_id\",date_at=\"$this->date_at\",time_at=\"$this->time_at\",tecnico_id=\"$this->tecnico_id\",project_id=\"$this->project_id\",priority_id=\"$this->priority_id\",description=\"$this->description\",status_id=\"$this->status_id\",kind_id=\"$this->kind_id\",updated_at=NOW() where id=$this->id";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }

    public static function getById($id){
        $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." where id=$id";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::one($query[0],new TicketData());
    }

    public static function getRepeated($pacient_id,$medic_id,$date_at,$time_at){
        $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." where pacient_id=$pacient_id and medic_id=$medic_id and date_at=\"$date_at\" and time_at=\"$time_at\"";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::one($query[0],new TicketData());
    }



    public static function getByMail($mail){
        $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." where mail=\"$mail\"";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::one($query[0],new TicketData());
    }

    public static function getEvery(){
        $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename;
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new TicketData()); 
    }

    public static function getEvents(){
        $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename;
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new TicketData());
    }

    public static function getAll(){
        $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." order by created_at desc";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new TicketData());
    }

    public static function getAllPendings(){
        $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." where status_id=1";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new TicketData());
    }


    public static function getAllByPacientId($id){
        $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." where pacient_id=$id order by created_at";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new TicketData());
    }

    public static function getAllByMedicId($id){
        $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." where medic_id=$id order by created_at";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new TicketData());
    }

    public static function getBySQL($sql){
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new TicketData());
    }

    public static function getOld(){
        $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." where date(date_at)<date(NOW()) order by date_at";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new TicketData());
    }

    public static function getLike($q){
        $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." where title like '%$q%'";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        return Model::many($query[0],new TicketData());
    }


}

?>
```

**UPDATE**

Made slight changes to TicketData.php correcting @smith's and @Nick's observations.
They look like this:

```
class TicketData {
    public static $tablename = "ticket";
    public function TicketData(){
        $this->name = "";
        $this->title = "";
        $this->description= "";
        $this->lastname = "";
        $this->email = "";
        $this->password = "";
        $this->date_at="";
        $this->time_at="";
        $this->tecnico_id="";
        $this->created_at = "NOW()";
    }
    public function getProject(){ return ProjectData::getById($this->project_id); }
    public function getPriority(){ return PriorityData::getById($this->priority_id); }
    public function getStatus(){ return StatusData::getById($this->status_id); }
    public function getKind(){ return KindData::getById($this->kind_id); }
    public function getCategory(){ return CategoryData::getById($this->category_id); }
    public function add(){
        $sql = "insert into ticket (title,description,date_at,time_at,category_id,project_id,priority_id,user_id,status_id,kind_id,created_at,tecnico_id) ";
        $sql .= "values (\"$this->title\",\"$this->description\",\"$this->date_at\",\"$this->time_at\",\"$this->category_id\",\"$this->project_id\",\"$this->priority_id\",\"$this->user_id\",\"$this->status_id\",\"$this->kind_id\",\"$this->created_at\",\"$this->tecnico_id\")";
        return Executor::doit($sql);
    }
```

Now, *it will* save these fields:

1. Ticket type (`kind_id`)
2. Ticket title (`title`)
3. Ticket description (`description`)
4. Date requested (`date_at`)
5. Hour requested (`hour_at`)
6. Company (`project_id`)
7. Type of visit (`category_id`)
8. Priority (`priority_id`)
9. Status (`status_id`)

*It won't* save this field:

1. Technician assigned (`tecnico_id`)

**addticket-action.php**

```
    <?php
        $r = new TicketData();
        $r->title = $_POST["title"];
        $r->description = $_POST["description"];
        $r->category_id = $_POST["category_id"];
        $r->project_id = $_POST["project_id"];
        $r->priority_id = $_POST["priority_id"];
        $r->user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
        $r->status_id = $_POST["status_id"];
        $r->kind_id = $_POST["kind_id"];
        $r->date_at = $_POST["date_at"];
        $r->time_at = $_POST["time_at"];
        $r->tecnico_id = $_POST["tecnico_id"];
        $r->created_at = $_POST["created_at"];
        $r->add();
        Core::alert("Successfully added!");
        Core::redir("./index.php?view=tickets");
 ?>
```

I want to make everything work *before* sanitizing and converting to a proper *prepared statement*.
What do I need to correct/add to make the script save the (`date_at`) (`hour_at`) and (`tecnico_id`) fields?

Comment: Tip: Learn about query parameters.

Comment: i dint see `$this->title` etc ever being set

Comment: it should be `values`, not `value` in the `insert` query.

Comment: Class constructors shouldn't use the old style (`public function ClassName()`) since it was deprecated in PHP 7 and will be completely removed in future versions. Use `public function __construct()` instead. Your code would also be clearer if you define all properties (and their defaults) as properties, instead of implicitly adding them in the constructor.

Comment: You're also using multiple class properties in your code that simply don't exist. You also never set/populate the properties at any point. This code has several issues. How are you using this class? Are you setting the properties some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Providing some logs or backend error messages could be pretty helpful in troubleshooting this issue.

At first glance though, the major thing that jumps out is that you're not actually using a prepared statement. You're basically concatenating a string together to make a SQL statement, which is *very bad* for a couple reasons:

1. You're vulnerable to SQL injection. For example, if you put 
   `","",""); DROP TABLE ticket; --` into your title field, someone could nuke your ticket table because your code doesn't check for this.
2. You need to sanitize your inputs. If title contains a double quote, it will prematurely end your string input, causing your SQL to fail.

This is a pretty big security hole, so plug that up and save yourself some input sanitization headaches at the same time! If you convert to prepared statement and it works, then it was probably a sanitization issue. If it still doesn't work, get some logging statements in there and let's see what you have.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: strangely enough, it didn't displayed any error message. That was the reason why I asked here lol. I'll try to sanitize the code and see if that solves it  thanks

Comment: Oh, and by the way: I was curious and I typed `","",""); DROP TABLE ticket; --` into the title field.  Nothing happened. It didn't even saved the ticket.

Comment: That would tend to indicate that in addition to the above issues, there may be a connection error to the DB somewhere. Can you do a simple "select * from tickets limit 5" and get it to return?

Also with the Drop syntax, I provided a sample, but you'll have to put in enough quotes to fill out your inserts.

Comment: Yes, there was a connection error because I forgot to add the new fields to `addticket-action.php`. Still, the code will "detect" this and won't save the ticket. If I type something else it will definitely save it.

Comment: That likely means there is still an error in the injection attack syntax - based on the above code, i promise you nothing is 'detecting' it and stopping the attack. It's your code to send to prod though, so sanitize it as you will. A ticket system is likely lower risk, but given you have emails and passwords in there you should really the the 15 min to make a prepared statement.